# Using Google Cloud Storage's public URL in Facebook `og:image` tags

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, facebook-opengraph, facebook-share

I'm using Google Cloud Storage to store my website's images, including the page's main image. Now, when I use that image's GCS URL in the `og:image` tag, Facebook won't show that image in the link preview.

A quick check in Facebook's Sharing Debugger returns this error:

```
Invalid content type: https://storage.googleapis.com/moonhope-174701.appspot.com/1548993318172Suasana%20RM%20-%20Kartika%20Abrindah%20Ngantung.jpg ould not be processed as an image because it has an invalid content type.
```

Here's the URL of the page it's shared from. Note that it might be different from the content of `og:url`

```
https://amborjo.com/restaurants/rm-syully-wakeke-f91e076125d411e991cc6db964093b53
```

The images in my site were uploaded to GCS using `@google-cloud/storage` Node.js module and uploaded with `contentType` metadata already set.

How do I fix this error?

Comment: a real example would be better, hard to help with that fictional link

Comment: @luschn I've updated the link.

Comment: can you add the shared url too, where that image is being used?

Comment: @luschn I've added the page's URL to the question.

Comment: why is there whitespace in the image url? NEVER do that...it may even be the problem, who knows.

Comment: Hm, maybe that trips up Facebook. The `content` property in the `meta` tag is enclosed by parentheses, though. Maybe Facebook doesn't URL-encode `og`'s

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem without a simple solution that occurs with Facebook, iMessage, and various other services that use image tags for previews.

The most straightforward way that I've found to resolve it is to configure your application to serve images from Google Cloud Storage. The directions for doing so with node.js are at:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/using-cloud-storage